# Selenium moveByOffset does not move focus to provided co-ordinates

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Issue**: I'm trying to scroll in Selenium using moveByOffset(x,y), however, the cursor is not shifting focus to the provided co-ordinates -

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //Find page height
    int pageHeight = ((Number) js.executeScript("return window.innerHeight")).intValue();

    //moveByOffset not working
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.moveByOffset(500, 300).click().build().perform();
```

**Objective:** Find the length of the page and scroll taking screenshots until the end of page is reached. (I've made a separate method for handling screenshots)

This has been discussed in thread - [Selenium moveByOffset doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703159/selenium-movebyoffset-doesnt-do-anything), but unsure if it has been resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page scroll up or down in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)

Comment: In the link you provided, there is an answer that links to a bug in that method. I would instead use one of the methods listed in the answer I linked above.

Comment: @JeffC - Thank you. Your linked post answered my question - I was curious as following the bug (in my attached link) seems to have been closed long ago. Ideally, moveByOffset should be working now OR did I make a mistake in my code? - just wanted to be sure in either case

Comment: I didn't read it that carefully. From what I remember, they closed the bug but people were still reporting the same bug after the fixed version. I didn't look any further than that. There may be a new bug in their list?